# Change bounds of integral

Tags: integration

I want to change the bounds of this integral from $0,2t$ to $0,t$ (for Laplace transform)

I try using an extra variable $x=2t$ but I can't realize how to change the $\sin:$

$$
f(t) = \int_0^{2t}    \sin (u)\, du.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Now $u \in (0,2t)$ and let $v = u/2 \in (0,t)$ so you have
$$
\int_0^{2t} \sin(u) du = \int_0^t \sin(2v) d(2v) = 2\int_0^t \sin(2v)dv.
$$